# How to run multiple linear regression models for columns that start at different times, with a new dataframe as output, in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I am trying to run multiple linear regression models with columns in a dataframe that all start at different times.

```
df = structure(list(Date_Time_GMT_3 = 
                      structure(c(1622552400, 1622553300,1622554200, 1622555100, 1622556000, 1622556900), 
                                class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), 
                                tzone = "EST"),
                    X20819830_R1AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 16.808, 16.713, 17.753), 
                    X20819742_R1AR_S_Stationary = c(16.903, 16.828, 16.808, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                    X20822215_R3AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 13.942, 13.942, 13.846), 
                    X20822215_R3AR_S_Stationary = c(13.942, 13.972, 13.842, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                    X20874235_R4AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 14.134, 14.534, 14.404), 
                    X20874235_R4AR_S_Stationary = c(14.23, 14.23, 14.134, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                    X20874311_F1AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 15.187, 15.327, 15.567), 
                    X20874311_F1AR_S_Stationary = c(15.282, 15.387, 15.587, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                    X20817727_F8AR_U = c(15.421, 14.441, 14.631, 14.781, 15.521, 15.821), 
                    X20819742_X1AR_U = c(14.996, 15.996, 14.776, 14.920, 14.870, 14.235), 
                    X20819742_R2AR_U = c(14.781, 15.521, 15.821, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                    X20817727_R5AR_U = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 13.942, 13.942, 13.846), 
                    X20817727_R7AR = c(14.23, 14.23, 14.134, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying perform a linear regression model for all columns WITHOUT `stationary` in the column name to columns WITH `stationary` in the column name (i.e. `stationary` on the x-axis). However, as you can see in the sample dataframe, all the columns start and end at different times, so I also need the linear regression model to only run when the `stationary` and non-stationary columns have values at the same time.

Overall, I would like the output of the code to give me all the values for each "non-stationary" logger when run against each `stationary` logger. For example, a table like the one below...

```
X20819830_R1AR_U_Stationary
Logger_ID        Reg_equation R_Squared Estimate_Std. Std_Error  Pr_t..
  <chr>            <int>               <int>     <int>        <int>     <int>   
1 X20676887_F8AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
2 X20819831_X1AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
3 X20822214_R2AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA  
1 X20676887_R7AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
2 X20819831_R5AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
    

X20822215_R3AR_U_Stationary
Logger_ID        Reg_equation R_Squared Estimate_Std. Std_Error  Pr_t..
  <chr>            <int>               <int>     <int>        <int>     <int>   
1 X20676887_F8AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
2 X20819831_X1AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
3 X20822214_R2AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA  
1 X20676887_R7AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA      
2 X20819831_R5AR_U NA                  NA        NA            NA         NA
```

I have code that can do it if I only have 1 `stationary` column, and if all the columns have values for the entire time.... which looks like so

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("X")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(X20819830_R3AR_U_Stationary ~ value, data = df) %>% 
      glance() %>% 
      # tidy() %>%  
      add_column(name = unique(df$name), .before=1)
  })
```

but as you can see it only takes into account 1 `stationary` column
, and when I run it with example dataframe I provided I get this error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
object 'X20819830_R3AR_U_Stationary' not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Let's check whether I understand your question right: All STATIONARY columns are responses Yi and all non STATIONARY columns (except for the time index) are predictors Xi. You want to run regressions lm(Yi ~ Xi) for each possible combination of predictor and response. And it's important that the observations are taken at the same time, so ignore any points where either Xi or Yi is NA.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that it is clear what you want to achieve, it turns out it's pretty easy to do by applying `pivot_longer` twice, once for stationary and then for non-stationary loggers.

*Aside*: Please look at how to correct for multiple hypothesis testing when interpreting the results. This is a lot of regressions.

```r
library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

extract_statistics <- function(fit) {
  bind_cols(
    # Extract statistics about model coefficients
    tidy(fit) %>% filter(term != "(Intercept)"),
    # Extract statistics about model fit
    glance(fit) %>% select(matches("r.squared"))
  )
}

results <-
  as_tibble(df) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    ends_with("STATIONARY"),
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  ) %>%
  # Every column other than the time index & the newly minted response & y columns
  # corresponds to a non-stationary logger.
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, response, y),
    names_to = "predictor",
    values_to = "x"
  ) %>%
  # It's not strictly necessary; `lm` drops data points with missing values
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(
    response, predictor
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    # ~ tidy(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
    # ~ glance(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
    ~ extract_statistics(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
results
#> # A tibble: 28 × 9
#>    response       predictor term  estimate std.error statistic p.value r.squared
#>    <chr>          <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 X20819742_R1A… X2081772… x       0.0893   0.0362      2.47   0.245     0.859 
#>  2 X20819742_R1A… X2081772… x       0.599    0.677       0.885  0.539     0.439 
#>  3 X20819742_R1A… X2081974… x      -0.0932   0.00776   -12.0    0.0528    0.993 
#>  4 X20819742_R1A… X2081974… x      -0.0117   0.0761     -0.154  0.903     0.0231
#>  5 X20819830_R1A… X2081772… x       0.712    0.804       0.886  0.539     0.440 
#>  6 X20819830_R1A… X2081772… x     -10.3      0.857     -12.1    0.0527    0.993 
#>  7 X20819830_R1A… X2081974… x      -1.49     0.222      -6.70   0.0944    0.978 
#>  8 X20822215_R3A… X2081772… x       0.0154   0.130       0.118  0.925     0.0138
#>  9 X20822215_R3A… X2081772… x       1.20     0.271       4.43   0.141     0.951 
#> 10 X20822215_R3A… X2081974… x      -0.0703   0.106      -0.663  0.627     0.305 
#> # … with 18 more rows, and 1 more variable: adj.r.squared <dbl>
```

Let's see the pairs of loggers that cause the warnings about a perfect fit:

```r
results %>%
  slice_min(
    std.error,
    n = 2
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>   response       predictor term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value r.squared
#>   <chr>          <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 X20822215_R3A… X2081772… x            1  1.77e-16   5.65e15 1.13e-16         1
#> 2 X20874235_R4A… X2081772… x            1  1.77e-16   5.65e15 1.13e-16         1
#> # … with 1 more variable: adj.r.squared <dbl>
```

Yep, perfect fit it is.

```r
df %>%
  select(X20822215_R3AR_U_Stationary, X20817727_R5AR_U)
#>   X20822215_R3AR_U_Stationary X20817727_R5AR_U
#> 1                          NA               NA
#> 2                          NA               NA
#> 3                          NA               NA
#> 4                      13.942           13.942
#> 5                      13.942           13.942
#> 6                      13.846           13.846

df %>%
  select(X20874235_R4AR_S_Stationary, X20817727_R7AR)
#>   X20874235_R4AR_S_Stationary X20817727_R7AR
#> 1                      14.230         14.230
#> 2                      14.230         14.230
#> 3                      14.134         14.134
#> 4                          NA             NA
#> 5                          NA             NA
#> 6                          NA             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

I apologize for the code duplication in advance. This is a followup in response to a further question from the OP.

Here is how to switch the role of *response* and *predictor*.

```r
df <- structure(list(
  Date_Time_GMT_3 =
    structure(c(1622552400, 1622553300, 1622554200, 1622555100, 1622556000, 1622556900),
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
      tzone = "EST"
    ),
  X20819830_R1AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 16.808, 16.713, 17.753),
  X20819742_R1AR_S_Stationary = c(16.903, 16.828, 16.808, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
  X20822215_R3AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 13.942, 13.942, 13.846),
  X20822215_R3AR_S_Stationary = c(13.942, 13.972, 13.842, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
  X20874235_R4AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 14.134, 14.534, 14.404),
  X20874235_R4AR_S_Stationary = c(14.23, 14.23, 14.134, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
  X20874311_F1AR_U_Stationary = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 15.187, 15.327, 15.567),
  X20874311_F1AR_S_Stationary = c(15.282, 15.387, 15.587, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
  X20817727_F8AR_U = c(15.421, 14.441, 14.631, 14.781, 15.521, 15.821),
  X20819742_X1AR_U = c(14.996, 15.996, 14.776, 14.920, 14.870, 14.235),
  X20819742_R2AR_U = c(14.781, 15.521, 15.821, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
  X20817727_R5AR_U = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 13.942, 13.942, 13.846),
  X20817727_R7AR = c(14.23, 14.23, 14.134, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
),
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"
)

library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

extract_statistics <- function(fit) {
  bind_cols(
    # Extract statistics about model coefficients
    tidy(fit) %>% filter(term != "(Intercept)"),
    # Extract statistics about model fit
    glance(fit) %>% select(matches("r.squared"))
  )
}

results <-
  as_tibble(df) %>%
  # Pivot non-stationary loggers
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, ends_with("STATIONARY")),
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  ) %>%
  # Every column other than the time index & the newly minted response & y columns
  # corresponds to a non-stationary logger.
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, response, y),
    names_to = "predictor",
    values_to = "x"
  ) %>%
  # It's not strictly necessary; `lm` drops data points with missing values
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(
    response, predictor
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    # ~ tidy(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
    # ~ glance(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
    ~ extract_statistics(lm(y ~ x, data = .))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable

#> Warning in summary.lm(x): essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
results
#> # A tibble: 28 × 9
#>    response      predictor term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value r.squared
#>    <chr>         <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 X20817727_F8… X2081974… x       9.62    3.90e+ 0  2.47e+ 0 2.45e- 1    0.859 
#>  2 X20817727_F8… X2081983… x       0.617   6.97e- 1  8.86e- 1 5.39e- 1    0.440 
#>  3 X20817727_F8… X2082221… x       0.896   7.58e+ 0  1.18e- 1 9.25e- 1    0.0138
#>  4 X20817727_F8… X2082221… x      -6.98    6.68e+ 0 -1.05e+ 0 4.86e- 1    0.522 
#>  5 X20817727_F8… X2087423… x       3.13    8.84e+ 0  3.53e- 1 7.84e- 1    0.111 
#>  6 X20817727_F8… X2087423… x       2.15    1.50e+ 0  1.44e+ 0 3.87e- 1    0.673 
#>  7 X20817727_F8… X2087431… x      -2.12    2.60e+ 0 -8.18e- 1 5.64e- 1    0.401 
#>  8 X20817727_F8… X2087431… x       2.58    1.06e+ 0  2.43e+ 0 2.49e- 1    0.855 
#>  9 X20817727_R5… X2081983… x      -0.0961  7.96e- 3 -1.21e+ 1 5.27e- 2    0.993 
#> 10 X20817727_R5… X2082221… x       1       1.77e-16  5.65e+15 1.13e-16    1     
#> # … with 18 more rows, and 1 more variable: adj.r.squared <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: so this works, but I am missing the r squared value. which is what I mostly need, so I can perform some interpolation later on.

Comment: Updated the answer. Would like to know what you mean by interpolation.

Comment: sorry, it's not important. I just need the r squared value

Comment: I realized the ```stationary``` columns are the independent variable, which means they are the predictor (i.e. would be on the x-axis). So I tried to switch around the variables in your code and I noticed when I changed them, the term column has a numeric value with an x (ex. ```15.325x```). It's clearly not working. Do you know how I can get similar results but have the ```stationary``` as the predictor/independent variable.

Comment: The code is quite general but you have to understand what it's doing. The two lines that determine which columns are selected as predictors and which as response, are the lines right after *pivot_longer*. Take a look at *ends_with("STATIONARY")* and *-c(Date_Time_GMT_3, response, y)* and read the documentation for *pivot_longer*.

Comment: It also helps to run the code section by section. That's why pipes `%>%` are handy.

Comment: yes I've tried this, but for some reason I can't see why the ```term``` column is giving me individual numbers when I switch predictor and response. And I've tried switching in multiple ways.

Comment: Change `ends_with("STATIONARY")` to `-c(Date_Time_GMT_3, ends_with("STATIONARY"))` and try again. Don't change anything else. Note: There is a minus sign before the *c(...)*.

Comment: Nope same results that I've been getting when I try to change the variables around. To be clear I changed ```pivot_longer(    ends_with("STATIONARY"),``` to ```pivot_longer( -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, ends_with("STATIONARY")),```

Comment: Okay. Let me post the reprex as it seems to work for me.

Comment: Ok, I see it works. It was a problem with the format of my dataframe.